# Build to Output path based off environment

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to figure out how to build and deploy an Angular 2 project built with angular cli based off of variables in my environment typescript files.

For example, my angular-cli.json file has a dev environment declared that points to "environments/environment.dev.ts". This file has the following properties:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  'output-path': '\\\\testServer\\apps\\appName\\'
};
```

What I would like to do is be able to call ng build --dev, and the cli would build the app with the dev file (which it does correctly), but also output it to the output-path, which in this case would be a network share. Is there anyway to do this without incorporating some other CI tool and/or gulp?

I have manually added the -o (--output-path) option when building and passed the path, but I don't want to build a solution for the company that would require developers to manually type paths each time.

I am aware I could update the package.json to add new commands for build/deploy with the --output-path parameter, but that would require updating the paths in multiple files and adding lots of new commands (ones for local, dev, test, prod).

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Comment: If you are on .NET project, couldn't you just use the `Project Publish` feature and add the right command in it?

Comment: This isn't a .NET project, it's an angular project built in VS Code (some other developers use WebStorm)

Answer (score 24):

Update for Angular 6+:

Set it in the angular.json:

For the development env:

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/dev",
```

For the production env:

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "outputPath": "dist/prod",
```

Comment: @johnnydevnull It didn't work for me. I am using Angular 7.2.0

Comment: I can confirm this works for Angular 13 LTS. It also works nicely for simultaneously building staging vs prod copies of an app in monorepo structure

Answer (score 9):

There are flags for the `ng build` command to handle what you need...

```
--target=development (or -dev)
--target=production (or -prod)
&
--output-path=my/output/path
```

So you can create npm scripts to do them in conjuction:

```
//in package.json
"scripts": {
  "devbuild": "ng build -dev --output-path=my/dev/output",
  "prodbuild": "ng build -prod --output-path=my/prod/output"
}
```

then you can just run....

```
npm run devbuild
npm run prodbuild
```

Comment: Ya I was aware I could create new scripts in the package.json, I was just hoping there was some way that the environment files could be used. It's really a shame that the environment files can't store all that info and be consumed by the build commands.

Comment: Nothing like that exists in the CLI, you will need to address in a manner external what the CLI offers. If you'd like the CLI to offer this, please create an issue on the repo.